# 'dbclick' event listener not working but 'click' is

Tags: javascript, dom, parameters, addeventlistener

Currently, I am making a password storing website. Part of the UI is when you double click on a password item it gives you the option to delete it.

Here is my event listner (with function), `myPasswordScreenID` is the parent element to all the classes with `passwordItem`.

```
document.getElementById('myPasswordsScreenID').addEventListener('dbclick', function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('passwordItem')) {
    if (confirm('Would you like to delete this item? It will be gone forever!')) {
      event.target.style.display = 'none';
      event.target.style.margin = 0;
      localStorage.removeItem(event.target.id);
    }
  }
}, false);
```

For some reason if I use the event listener 'click' instead of 'dbclick' it works? I have no clue why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect double clicks with [`dblclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event).

Comment: Wow ok, I thought that almost all browsers supported dbclick. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@AndreaOggioni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9173871/andrea-oggioni)'s answer, using the code from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event):

```
const element = document.getElementById('myPasswordsScreenID');

element.addEventListener('dblclick', function(event) {
  if (
    event.target.classList.contains('passwordItem') &&
    confirm('Would you like to delete this item? It will be gone forever!')
  ) {
    event.target.style.display = 'none';
    event.target.style.margin = 0;
    localStorage.removeItem(event.target.id);
  }
});
```

Good luck.